# how to list all files and directories that have the maximum number of the same inode number

Tags: linux, bash, shell, inode

how to list all files and directories that have the maximum number of the same inode number in the home directory?

for example:

inode file/directory name

```
112233 file1
112233 myfile
112233 myDocs

345566 Docs
345566 Downloads
```

then it should print

```
/home/sysadmin/file1
/home/sysadmin/myfile
/home/sysadmin/myDocs
```

as the inode 112233 has more links than the inode 345566

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to change the `text=$(ls -ldi ~/*);` line.

```
#!/bin/bash

text=$(ls -ldi ~/*);
echo "$text" | grep -i "^$(echo "$text" | sed '/^$/d' |cut -d' ' -f1 | uniq -c | sort -r | awk '{print $2}' | head -n 1)" | awk 'NF>1{print $NF}';
```

Comment: That's true. Then you can list after the second argument if the input is as you specified. If the name of the file contains a newline, it will appear as 'foo'$'\n''bar'.